# При выполнении программы вне Intellij IDEA нет записи в Postgresql

Tags: java, postgresql, intellij-idea

Здравствуйте.
Написал программу-парсер на Java. Запускаю её в среде разработки Intellij IDEA, программа по окончании парсинга записывает все полученные данные в БД postgresql, закрываю программу, проверяю БД - появились новые записи. Делаю исполняемый jar-файл, запускаю, программа отрабатывает без ошибок, закрываю, проверяю БД - нет записей. Пробовал предварительно очистить БД - всё-равно ничего не записывается.
В какую сторону "копать"?

Comment: может у вас в Watchers висит метод `commitToDb()` ? попробуйте почистить Watchers  и проверить через студию

Comment: Интересно. Как это сделать?))

Comment: http://ipic.su/img/img7/fs/123.1481788502.png

Comment: Обязательно завтра попробую и отпишусь, спасибо.

Comment: Прошёл дебагером, нет увидел такого метода, к сожалению.

Answer (score 0):

как вариант запустить приложение из командной строки, так по крайней мере можно увидеть ошибки, если они есть.. так же можно логирование (хотя бы простые принты на консоль) добавить чтобы были видны этапы отработки приложения и тогда станет ясно, где затык

Comment: Да, после успешной записи в БД, лог отражается в GUI